# error LNK2019 and LNK1120

Tags: c

It is a known Topic, but i cant find the solution.

What i did:
createt and console Application.
Add a c source File
Add The path to my Header File to "additional include directorys"
write my code( or ctrl+c + crtl+v)
compile = error

Firste the Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sndfile.h>

int main()
{
SNDFILE *sf;
SF_INFO info;
int num_channels;
int num, num_items;
int *buf;
int f,sr,c;
int i,j;
FILE *out;

/* Open the WAV file. */
info.format = 0;
sf = sf_open("file.wav",SFM_READ,&info);
if (sf == NULL)
    {
    printf("Failed to open the file.\n");
    exit(-1);
    }
/* Print some of the info, and figure out how much data to read. */
f = info.frames;
sr = info.samplerate;
c = info.channels;
printf("frames=%d\n",f);
printf("samplerate=%d\n",sr);
printf("channels=%d\n",c);
num_items = f*c;
printf("num_items=%d\n",num_items);
/* Allocate space for the data to be read, then read it. */
buf = (int *) malloc(num_items*sizeof(int));
num = sf_read_int(sf,buf,num_items);
sf_close(sf);
printf("Read %d items\n",num);
/* Write the data to filedata.out. */
out = fopen("filedata.out","w");
for (i = 0; i < num; i += c)
    {
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j)
        fprintf(out,"%d ",buf[i+j]);
    fprintf(out,"\n");
    }
fclose(out);
return 0;
}
```

The Error Message:

> 1>SoundIO.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_sf_open" in Funktion "_main".
>
> 1>SoundIO.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_sf_read_int" in Funktion "_main".
>
> 1>SoundIO.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_sf_close" in Funktion "_main".
>
> 1>C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\BA\Audio_Coding\SoundIO\Debug\SoundIO.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 nicht aufgelöste Externe

The Settings: http://img5.picload.org/image/lccigod/settings.png

What i wanted to do? Simply this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=968690

What i need? A way to fix this (And how to do it) or an easy guide to get this running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker is telling you that you are missing definitions for the functions from libsndfile. You need to either:

1. Compile libsndfile from its sources, and link the resulting objects to your program.
2. Link an import library for libsndfile so that you can dynamically link to libsndfile.

Which solution you opt for depends on how you want to link to libsndfile.

Comment: "Compile libsndfile from its sources, and link the resulting objects to your program."
My Header file is just "broken"?

Comment: No. This is a linker error rather than a compiler error. I think that you may need to revise how C programs are compiled and linked, and what the difference is between compilation and linking.

Comment: I added the path in General Setiings under C/C++ and Linker, i also added the File into the source and include directory. I dont know why this isnt working at all. I am using the library file from the Windows installer. I never worked with Visual Studio before. Why is it so hard to use a simple Library?

Answer (score 0):

From: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/compiler_linker_errors.html

> You may have issues with how you set up your compiler. For instance,
>   even if you include the correct header files for all of your functions,
>   you still need to provide your linker with the correct path to the library
>   that has the actual implementation. Otherwise, you will get "undefined function"
>   error messages...

While it looks like you've correctly included the necessary headers in your code and you've got everything compiling, you need to either statically or dynamically link to libsndfile in order to resolve your linker errors.

Answer (score -1):

If you are including header files then you must ensure that they are in the include directory of your C++ directory. If it is an external file then you must add their path to your project from project properties.

Comment: if you are not adding additional files it cause a linker error not a compiler error. Check linker settings from project properties and make you have given a reference to those files there.